# Why do the VS Graphics Diagnostics disable the VS hosting process?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have noticed that whenever I use the [Graphics Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/graphics/visual-studio-graphics-diagnostics) tools in Visual Studio, the following setting is set in all of the project files in the solution:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
  <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In other words, the [VS hosting process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/hosting-process-vshost-exe) is always disabled by the Graphics tools. Why is this? Is there something about the hosting process that makes it incompatible with the graphics tools? If not, is there a way to turn this behavior off so that we can continue to use the hosting process (for apps that need it) with the graphics tools?

Comment: My understanding is that the hosting process will impact the performance, but the Graphics Diagnostics tool was used to collect/find the performance issue, maybe they are conflicting. Anyway, I will discuss with other members, if I get any latest information, I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is how we hook the process. We need to be in the process right at the beginning. The hosting process actually runs as soon as you start a project, and since you're not always doing graphics debugging, we didn't stick ourselves into the hosting process too.